# Cakephp 3.3.10 - IIS 8 - PHP 7.1 - MSSQL 2016 : Cannot describe settings. It has 0 columns

Tags: sql-server, iis, cakephp-3.0

I have integrated Cakephp (3.3.10) with MSSQL 2016 and installed on IIS 8.

I have created a table `settings` and relevant Table Class file,  and for testing I have used **find()** query on **TableRegistry** object.

I am getting following error in the browser :

`Cannot describe settings. It has 0 columns.`

I also found that in **tmp\cache\model**, there is no model cache file generated for model `Settings`. There is no permission issue either. As debugkit related files are being written in model folder.

I have posted the same here on Git : https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/10450

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.